# ng-class with scope that has multiple values

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-class

I would like to add a class based on the value of the scope. 
It's not working :(

If the `value.statut == 3`, I would like to add class `todo`

Else If `the value.statut == 2`, I would like to add class `done`

Else If `the value.statut == 1`, I would like to add class `doing`

```
  <span class="label" ng-class="value.statut == 3 ? 'todo' : ''; value.statut == 2 ? 'done' : ''; value.statut == 1 ? 'doing' : '';">Label</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration needs to be slightly different:

```
<span class="label" ng-class="{'todo': value.statut == 3, 'done': value.statut == 2, 'doing': value.statut == 1}">Label</span>
```

So, the syntax is:

```
ng-class="{<className>: <predicate>, <className2>: <predicate2>, etc }"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
<span class="label" ng-class="{'todo': (value.statut == 3), 'done': (value.statut == 2), 'doing': (value.statut == 1)}">Label</span>
```

`ng-class` needs an object with key/value. The key is the class name and the value is a boolean.

---

*Reference*

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass